# Remove background color highlight for colors in SASS in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm shows me the colour in my SCSS with a highlight. I want to keep the colour in the margin to the left, but remove the highlight of the actual color hex value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor`
2. `General | Appearance`
3. `Show CSS color preview as background` option

P.S. File re-opening or even IDE restart may be required.

[image]